# How would i put my "outputs" into a type of table such as the one i have included?

Tags: javascript

I want to make each of these outputs appear in a table. I have no idea on how to move the "outputs" so that they can look somewhat like the one which i created within excel. I would like it to look something like the image below; is this possible?
[image]

Also, this is what the code looks like currently:

[image]

This is the code that i currently have which creates the outputs:

```
<script>
"use strict;"
function byId(id){return document.getElementById(id)}
window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false);

function onLoaded(evt)
{
  let input = byId('myInput');
  input.addEventListener('input', onInputReceived, false);
}

function onInputReceived(evt)
{
  let outputs = [byId('output1'), byId('output2'), byId('output3'), byId('output4'), byId('output5'), byId('output6')];
  let value = parseFloat(this.value);
  if (!isNaN(value))
  {
    outputs[0].textContent = Math.ceil( value / 0.7);
    outputs[1].textContent = Math.ceil( value * 1);
    outputs[2].textContent = Math.ceil( value / 0.7 - (value / 0.7 /  100*40));
    outputs[3].textContent = Math.ceil( value * 1);
    outputs[4].textContent = Math.ceil( value / 0.7 - (value / 0.7 /  100*20));
    outputs[5].textContent = Math.ceil( value / 0.7 - (value / 0.7 /  100*10));
  }
  else
  {
    outputs[0].textContent = 
    outputs[1].textContent = 
    outputs[2].textContent = 
    outputs[3].textContent = 
    outputs[4].textContent = 
    outputs[5].textContent = "*invalid input (enter a number)*";
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <label><strong>Enter NHS Price -
      <input id="myInput">
    </strong></label>
    <br>
<ul>
  <label> <strong> Retail: </strong></label>                
        <li id='output1'></li>  
        <br>
        
        <label> <strong> Schools &amp; CDC's: </strong></label>     
        <li id='output2'></li> 
        <br>
        
        <label> <strong> Trade - Band A: </strong></label>       
        <li id='output3'></li> 
        <br>
        
        <label> <strong> Trade - Band B: </strong></label>      
        <li id='output4'></li> 
        <br>
        
        <label> <strong> Trade - Band C: </strong></label>       
        <li id='output5'></li> 
        <br>
        
        <label> <strong> Trade - Band D: </strong></label>       
        <li id='output6'></li>
        
        
    </ul>
```

Comment: _"I have no idea on how to..."_ - First step: use an actual table instead of an unordered list

Comment: But that then stops the code from working when i change the unordered list to a table

Comment: You will need to fix the markup though ... having `label` as direct children of `ul`? no, just no `Permitted content  Zero or more <li>, <script> and <template> elements.`

Comment: To be frank, you need to change the HTML a LOT to make it possible to style it as you want to - the changes should not effect the code too much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quite big changes to the markup

but the javascript code is unchanged

and I think it's pretty close to what you're after

```js
function byId(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id)
}
window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false);

function onLoaded(evt) {
  let input = byId('myInput');
  input.addEventListener('input', onInputReceived, false);
}

function onInputReceived(evt) {
  let outputs = [byId('output1'), byId('output2'), byId('output3'), byId('output4'), byId('output5'), byId('output6')];
  let value = parseFloat(this.value);
  if (!isNaN(value)) {
    outputs[0].textContent = Math.ceil(value / 0.7);
    outputs[1].textContent = Math.ceil(value * 1);
    outputs[2].textContent = Math.ceil(value / 0.7 - (value / 0.7 / 100 * 40));
    outputs[3].textContent = Math.ceil(value * 1);
    outputs[4].textContent = Math.ceil(value / 0.7 - (value / 0.7 / 100 * 20));
    outputs[5].textContent = Math.ceil(value / 0.7 - (value / 0.7 / 100 * 10));
  } else {
    outputs[0].textContent =
      outputs[1].textContent =
      outputs[2].textContent =
      outputs[3].textContent =
      outputs[4].textContent =
      outputs[5].textContent = "*invalid input (enter a number)*";
  }
}
```

```css
main {
  background-color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 25px;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}

#myInput {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}
#myInput:focus {
  outline:none;
}
header label {
  display:block;
}
header strong {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 8px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  
}

main>div>div,
header div {
  padding: 15px 18px;
  background: white;
}

main>div>div {
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding: 15px 8px;
}

main>div>div>strong {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align:center;
}

output {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  min-width: 10em;
}
output::before {
  content: '£';
}
output::after {
  clear: both;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<main>
  <header>
    <label>
      <strong>Enter NHS Price Below</strong>
        <div>
          <input id="myInput"/>
        </div>
    </label>
  </header>
  <div>
    <div>
      <strong>Retail:</strong>
      <output id='output1' />
    </div>
    <div>
      <strong>Schools &amp; CDC's:</strong>
      <output id='output2' />
    </div>
    <div>
      <strong>Trade - Band A:</strong>
      <output id='output3' />
    </div>
    <div>
      <strong>Trade - Band B:</strong>
      <output id='output4' />
    </div>
    <div>
      <strong>Trade - Band C:</strong>
      <output id='output5' />
    </div>
    <div>
      <strong>Trade - Band D:</strong>
      <output id='output6' />
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: how would i get this to work, is it html or javascript - when i put it into dreamweaver it is coming out as plain text

Comment: erm ... how did you use your code? that's how

Comment: i realised that pretty soon after i sent the message, thanks for your help